# How to get the raw "content" from all pages

Tags: ruby, sitemap, sprockets, middleman

I'm trying to make an index file for my Middleman site, and would like to include in that file the raw "content" of my pages. i.e.

/source/mypage.md:

```
---
title: My Page
---
# This is my page
With *my markdown*
```

and

/source/myotherpage.md:

```
---
title: My Other Page
---
# Here is my other page
```

I'd like to have a third page that's at `/source/site_index.json.erb` that when output looks something like:

```
 [
   {'title': 'My Page', 'body': '#This is my page\nWith *my markdown\n'},
   {'title': 'My Other Page', 'body': '#Here is my other page\n'}
 ]
```

I can get the title etc using something like this, but I don't know how to get the raw body:

```
[
  <% sitemap.resources.select{|resource| resource.content_type == 'text/html; charset=utf-8' unless resource.data.ignore }.each do |resource| %>
    {
      "title": <%= resource.data.title.to_json %>,
      "body": <%= nil %>
    } ,
  <% end %>
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Never used Middleman before yet but have you tried `resource.render`?

According to the documentation at http://rubydoc.info/gems/middleman-core/Middleman/Sitemap/Resource#render-instance_method it seems like it should work.

Another potential lead is the following reference to `raw_body_content` at https://github.com/middleman/middleman-sitemap-api/blob/master/lib/middleman-sitemap-api/extension.rb#L122

Hope this helps

Comment: `resource.render` returns the final HTML output, not the original source (Markdown in my case). The `raw_body_content` looks promising, but requires a reference to a "middleman" var that I'm not seeing.

Comment: No, as I explained above, there are a couple issues.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry - I saw your comment before you edited it. Let me take a few more looks..

Answer (score 1):

The `resource` object has a pointer to the source file (`source_file`) and you could just read the file content:

```
[
    <%
    pages = sitemap.resources.select{|resource| resource.content_type == 'text/html; charset=utf-8' unless resource.data.ignore }
    pages.each_with_index do |resource, index|
        file = File.open(resource.source_file, 'r')
        content = file.read
    %>
    {
        "title": <%= resource.data.title.to_json %>,
        "body": <%= content.to_json %>
    } <%=',' unless( index == pages.length-1) %>
    <% end %>
]
```

This worked for me, tested with Middleman 3.3.3.